# Decomposition of a Lipschitz domain as union of strongly star shaped Lipschitz domains

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> **Definition.** We say that $\Omega$ is a *strongly star shaped*
>   domain (with respect to $x_0$) in $\mathbb R ^n$ if: 
>   $$
> \Omega  = \left\{x\in \mathbb R ^n :  \| x-x_0  \| < g\Big(\frac{x-x_0}{\| x-x_0  \|}\Big)\right\}
> $$
>   and 
>   $$
> \partial \Omega  = \left\{x\in \mathbb R ^n :  \| x-x_0  \| = g\Big(\frac{x-x_0}{ \| x-x_0  \|}\Big)\right\}
> $$
>   with $g$ is a continuous, positive function on the unit sphere.

In this [paper](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~bramble/psfiles/infsup1018.pdf) 
Bramble use the fact that : **Any Lipschitz domain can be written as the union
of strongly star shaped Lipschitz domains: $\Omega=\bigcup_{i=1}^{M}\Omega_i$**

Can you help me to find Why we have this result?

I would appreciate if you could answer me.

Comment: The idea is that a Lipschitz domain $\Omega$ for which there exists a ball $B\subset \Omega$ such that every point in $\Omega$ can be joined to any point in $B$ by a line is star-shaped (to see that the defining function is Lipschitz you can appeal to the interior cone characterization of Lipchitz functions). This allows you to show that the domain above a Lipschitz graph satisfies your conclusion and for a general (bounded) Lipschitz domain we cover the boundary by open sets where the boundary is given a the graph of a Lipschitz function.

Comment: Bramble doesn't seem to make your statement.  At the bottom of page 2 he states, "Clearly if $\cup^M_{j=1}\Omega_j$ and if (1.7) holds for each $\Omega_j, j=1,\dots,M<\infty$, then it holds for $\Omega$.  We will use the fact that any Lipschitz domain can be written as the union of strongly star shaped Lipschitz domains."  I can't see anywhere where he claims that that the finite decomposition you've presented is true.

Comment: @postmortes: After your quote Bramble states "Hence we may assume, without loss, that $\Omega$ is strongly star-shaped". The only way this reduction is valid is if the decomposition that Mokata mentions is true.

Comment: @Jose27 -- ah, I see what you mean!  Thank-you :)

Comment: Thank you for your replies, @Jose27  Can you explain your idea, I did not understand it..

Comment: Now asked on MathOverflow: [Decompostition of a Lipschitz domain](https://mathoverflow.net/q/269801). You can find links to some basic info about cross-posting [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info). Personally, I consider the advice given in [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) very reasonable.